# If I shard my microservice data by enduser/tenant and each server has a subset of the total data, how do I query for data across all servers?

Tags: microservices, data-warehouse, scalability

Imagine a highly scalable architecture where each tenant is sharded and distributed by region and availability zone and each server holds a subset of total data. There is also redundancy, there are physical shards that host the same logical shard.

This works great, clients can use a map/reduce style to retrieve all data when handling requests that return extreme amounts of data if they know all the logical shards that a user is assigned to. This solves the problem if the amount of data for a user is larger than the capacity of any individual server's storage or memory or compute.

My question then is, if the data for a noun microservice is isolated and sharded across multiple servers and every server hosts a different subset of users or tenants, how do I create a view of all the objects in the system? I've effectively denormalised for performance but that means there is extreme read amplification to see the total number of objects in the system.

If I wanted a GUI that would show me all the noun objects of each microservice, and there is N physical shards and M noun services, I would need to create N×M requests to fetch all the data, sort it for presentation. It would be incredibly inefficient.

I'm thinking for more of an administration GUI perspective. Nobody wants to log into X microservice or microservice frontends to manage all the data in the system.

Is this a usecase for data warehousing or data lake?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a usecase for data warehousing or data lake?

Yes.  Replicating data into a central repository (Operational Data Store, Data Lake, or Data Warehouse) is common pattern in microservice and multi-tenant application architectures.